# Incorrect route being used - Express

Tags: node.js, express

I've got the following routes in express:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    console.log('rendering home page');
    res.render('index');
});

app.get('/:id', function(req, res){
    console.log('getting id');
});
```

Every time a request for the home page is made, the home page renders, but then I also see 'getting id' in the log. Why is the second route being triggered?

Comment: Please post the complete code for the home page.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your home page.
It is very likely that page has tags (e.g. LINK, SCRIPT, IMG) which makes requests to your server and pattern match your second route.